# Linq To Entities Decryption of specific columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encryption, linq-to-entities

My application is MVC 5, using EF 6.3.  I am trying to decrypt two columns using the following:

```
var grid = db.mytable.Where(c => c.Item== "Order").Select(c => new
            {
                FirstName = Encryption.Decrypt(c.FirstName),
                LastName = Encryption.Decrypt(c.LastName),
                Id = c.Id
             }).ToList();
```

I get this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   Decrypt(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

Comment: well, it means what it means ... linq cannot translate C# method to SQL ... materialize IQueryable first then apply your method ... asked multiple times here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that EF is trying to translate the code in your `Select` into SQL but there is no translation for the `Encryption.Decrypt` method to SQL. Instead, you need to execute the query and then do the decryption on the result set.

This can be accomplished by adding `ToList()` before the `Select` to force execution

```
var grid = db.mytable.Where(c => c.Item== "Order").ToList().Select(c => new
            {
                FirstName = Encryption.Decrypt(c.FirstName),
                LastName = Encryption.Decrypt(c.LastName),
                Id = c.Id
             }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `.ToList()` to make your query become [Immediate Query Execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution#immediate-query-execution). After that, you can do something as you wish.

```
var filteredTable = db.mytable.Where(c => c.Item== "Order").ToList();
var grid = filteredTable .Select(c => new
            {
                FirstName = Encryption.Decrypt(c.FirstName),
                LastName = Encryption.Decrypt(c.LastName),
                Id = c.Id
             }).ToList();
```